# Change the order by minimum order output in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to select the minimum of a string however due to sql ordering automatically in lexicographic order, its not in the correct order for what I require.

I currently have 3 seasons where I would like to select the minimum / order by the minimum. The code I currently have is:

```
Select distinct season from table1 order by season desc;
```

The order it currently outputs this is:

```
Spring19
Autumn19
Autumn18
```

However I need it to order as chronoligical order as the seasons go so:

```
Autumn18
Spring19
Autumn19
```

Is there a way that I can change the format to a 'date' without actually changing the format of the text? Or is there another way to do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Tag your query with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most databases support the `right()` function (if not, they have similar functionality by different names).

So, this should work:

```
Select distinct season
from table1
order by right(season, 2) asc, season desc;
```

Comment: Winter, Summer, Spring, Autumn? Don't you need to use CASE here?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson . . . The sample data only has two seasons.  Maybe the OP is from San Diego.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are correct, I am only using two seasons. This worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
with seasoncte (season_number, season_year, season) as (
  select case when left(season, length(season) -2) = "Spring" then 1
            when left(season, length(season) -2) = "Summer" then 2
            when left(season, length(season) -2) = "Autumn" then 3
            when left(season, length(season) -2) = "Winter  then 4
        end as season_number,
        cast(right(season,2 as int) as season_year,
        season
  from table1
), seasoncte2 (season_number, season_year, season) as (
   select season_number
          case when season_year < 39 then 2000 + season_year
          case else then 1900 + season_year
          end,
          season
   from seasoncte
)
select t1.season
from table1 t1
join seasoncte2 cte
on t1.season = cte.season
order by cte.season_year, cte.season_number
```

Code may need tweaking depending on SQL dialect.

Op did not specify that. Or provide rextester link, so code could be tested.